# How to properly store a pointer to the root of a binary search tree?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am attempting to insert a series of nodes into a binary search tree. I have set up the following main and struct. My issue is that when I print after the addition of each node the values `parent->name` and `(*insertLocation)->name`, they contain the data of the new node and not of the root of the tree, as I've intended. I believe it has something to do with the parent pointer somehow being reassigned and not retaining the value of the root. Is there some other way to retain the root of a binary tree?

```
typedef struct nodeT{
    char* name;
    char** data;
    struct nodeT* left;
    struct nodeT* right;
} node_t ;    

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    node_t *parent = NULL;
    node_t** Location = &parent;

    int i;
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRLEN);
    char** data = malloc(sizeof(char*)*NUMRECORDS);
    for (i = 0; i < NUMRECORDS; i++){
        data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRLEN);
    }
    add(Location, data, name);
}
```

My functions to insert a node are as follows:

```
node_t* newNode(char** data, char* name){

  node_t* node = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  node->data  = data;
  node->name  = name;
  node->left  = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  return node;
}

void add(node_t** insertLocation, char** data, char* name){

    node_t* curr = *insertLocation;
    if(curr == NULL){
        curr = newNode(data, name);
        *insertLocation = curr;
    }else{
        if(data[0] < curr->data[0]){
            add(&curr->left, data, name);
        }else{
            add(&curr->right, data, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You never put any data into `name` - is that intended? 2) Are you sure you want to store pointers in your tree - I would expect strings.

Comment: You should post the code where you do the printing that fails

Comment: This `data[0] < curr->data[0]` compares two pointers. I'm pretty sure that isn't what you want to do. I'll recommend that you edit your question and explain what you want the program to do. As it is now there seem to be something wrong with the data structure

Comment: Please give an example input, what you expected the structure to be, and what it was instead.  I agree with @4386427 that without seeing what you're passing for `data` it's hard to know your intent.  You can use indentation in text to show the expected tree, E.g., with the root at the left, and children on lines above and below indented rightward.